# how to use "that" properly

Tags: grammaticality, that

> We look forward to a revised ***proposal that*** the installation of lift
> will not lead to any loss of the school premises nor worsen the
> existing school environment.

Is ***proposal that*** alright? Or is *proposal **in** that* better?

Comment: Your question needs some more context. Explain where you found the link and provided if available. It would be good to also include the research you have made.

Comment: @fev it is from my own work.

Comment: Have you looked up the word proposal in the dictionary? What have you found?

Comment: Are you referring to the contents of the proposal, or the wider effects of the proposal?

Comment: @StuartF, the wider effects

Comment: @KannE, buy the way, is "the installation of lift" better?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is *proposal that* alright? Or is *proposal in that* better?

It depends on what you intend to mean. These expressions don't mean the same thing.

#### in that

> [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20that): used to introduce a statement that explains or gives more specific information about what one has just said

Or

> [AH](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=in%20that): For the reason that.

As for ***that***, it's being used as a conjunction here. This use may have several meanings you can find [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that).

Find the meaning you intend to convey, and you'll have your answer.